# Scala count each element in rdd

Tags: scala, rdd

I'm reading from csv file and I have a column that I want to count each element in it. I'm writing in scala.

```
def problem4(trips: RDD[Trip]): String = {
val result = trips.map(x=>x.zip_code).collect()
```

}

Comment: What about using `count()` which _(incredibly)_ returns the count of elements.

Comment: I want to count each zipcode

Comment: You may want to be more clear about your problem and your data, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Anyways, you probably want `trips.map(x => x.zip_code -> 1).reduceByKey(_ + _)`, I would advice you to take a look to the [**scaladoc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package) and follow any basic tutorial.

Comment: Ok I got it, could you tell me how can I sort them     val reducedRdd = pairRdd.reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey(false)

Comment: Sort them by what? By the count? In ascending or descending order?